# jQuery Ajax call error in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, safari

I have a WCF RESTful service exposed and I am trying to use a client to call those WCF RESTful services by using a jQuery ajax call. The code seems to work fine in IE 9 but gives error in Safari 5.0.3

This is the following piece of code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#butCallAjax').click(function () {


jQuery.support.cors = true;


            $.ajax(
                {

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://<server_name>/Service.svc/login',
                    data: '{"Domain":"mydomain","UserName":"myusername","Password":"mypassword"}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert('success');
                        $.each(data, function (i, theItem) {

                            try {
                                //alert('success add combo');
                              // Other browsers
                            }
                            catch (error) {
                                alert('error found');
//                                combo.add(option); // really old browser
                            }

                        });
                    },
                    error: function (msg, url, line) {
                        alert('error trapped in error: function(msg, url, line)');
                        alert('msg = ' + msg + ', url = ' + url + ', line = ' + line);

                    }
                });


            //alert('button click');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks! The error function is getting called from Safari and I can see the two alert pop-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got a solution to this; after doing a lot of trial and error for almost a week!

Added this in the global.asax file and safari seems to be able to access the POST methods!

```
String corsOrigin, corsMethod, corsHeaders;

corsOrigin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];
corsMethod = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];
corsHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];

if (corsOrigin == null || corsOrigin == "null")
{
    corsOrigin = "*";
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsOrigin);

if (corsMethod != null)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", corsMethod);

if (corsHeaders != null)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", corsHeaders);

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF is on a remote server and call is being made from another server then Ajax call can't be made on remote servers due to security concerns. Have a look at Same Origin Policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

To make a remote call use JSONP by using Jquery.getJSON() function. Check this link for details:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Actually this was working previously when I developed a small test application and tested it with "GET" method. The WCF service call did respond. Also I have Allow-Access-Allow-Origin:* so, cross domain access should be allowed, isnt it? Also, if it's not accessible then how come the call from IE works?